# ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter does not support skipping duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I'm having this problem when I'm trying to run rspec on Github actions. This is my github action workflow.

```
name: Ruby

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup System
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
      - name: Set up Ruby 2.7.2
        uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.7.2
      - name: Cache Ruby Gems
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: vendor/bundle
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gems-${{ hashFiles('**/Gemfile.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gems-
      - name: Bundle Install
        run: |
          bundle config path vendor/bundle
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3 --without=production
      - name: Setup DB
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          DISABLE_SPRING: 1
        run: |
          bin/rails db:setup db:migrate db:seed
      - name: Run rspec
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          DISABLE_SPRING: 1
        run: bundle exec rspec
```

- My code is calling `insert_all`.
- I was able to track the error down to https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/insert_all.rb#L97
- From what I can see, it has nothing to do with the data being insert but the connection itself
- For some reason the (sqlite3) connection doesn't support skipping duplicates
- I do not get this error on my local macbook air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr - I was using an old version of SQLite3

Okay, tracing the rail's code, I find that for the sqlite3 adapter it calls

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/da418dc2508eb8af94ba88b70034021cd17b1abd/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb#L152

which calls

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/da418dc2508eb8af94ba88b70034021cd17b1abd/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb#L149

which specifies that sqlite3 must be version 3.24.0 or great.

At the same time, Github's ubuntu-latest currently (02-2021) uses Ubuntu 18 as "latest".

And the sqlite3 package on Ubuntu installs sqlite 3.22 by default. source: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sqlite3

So after changing to `runs-on: ubuntu-20.04` I no longer get this problem!